# Is it possible to mix-in a module method?

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, mixins, composition

Let's say I have a module that declares a module method (**not** an instance method):

```
module M
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end
```

Now let's say I want to mix-in `M.foo` into another class `C` such that `C.foo` is defined.

Finally, I want to do this **without changing the way `M.foo` is defined** and **without just creating a method in `C` that calls `M.foo`**. (i.e. rewriting `foo` as an instance method doesn't count. Neither does using `module_function`.)

Is this impossible in Ruby?

Comment: No. If your intent is to mix-in a method that becomes a class method in class `C`, you must make the method in the module an instance method and use `C.extend M` (or `C.singleton_class.include M`). (See [Object#extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-extend)). To use module methods you must invoke the method on the module in which it is defined, the methods of the module [Math](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Math.html) being an example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Perfect answer! Thank you.

Comment: As an academic excercise you could copy all the class methods on `M` into instance methods, but it's better to just modify `M` to have the definitions as instance methods in the first place and possibly `extend self` if needed (or use `module_method`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do this **without changing the way `M.foo` is defined**

Unfortunately, that's not possible. Ruby only allows to include modules, not classes. `foo` however is defined on `M`'s singleton class which *is* a class. Therefore, you can't `include` it. The same restriction applies to `extend`. Trying to do so results in a `TypeError`:

```
module M
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end

class C
  extend M.singleton_class # TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
end
```

You can however achieve what you want by defining `foo` as an instance method in a separate module which can then be mixed into both, `M` and `C` via `extend`:  (that module doesn't have to be nested under `M`)

```
module M
  module SingletonMethods
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
  end

  extend SingletonMethods     # <- this makes foo available as M.foo
end

class C
  extend M::SingletonMethods  # <- this makes foo available as C.foo
end
```

Or with some metaprogramming magic using Ruby's [`included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included) callback:

```
module M
  module SingletonMethods
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
  end

  extend SingletonMethods

  def self.included(mod)
    mod.extend(SingletonMethods)
  end
end

class C
  include M
end
```

That's a simplified version of how [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) works in Rails.

Comment: A nice & simple answer, thank you. This was basically my conclusion after reading the MRI source—good to have it documented in an "official" form here.

Comment: @pje your question inspired me to ask this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59766403/477037

Comment: What a fascinating question! I'd never thought about that before.