# What prevents me from including a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, include

I'm trying to understand some Ruby internals:

Attempting to `include` a *class* instead of a *module*, results in a `TypeError`: (that's by design)

```
class C
end

class Foo
end

Foo.include(C)
#=> TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

I would like to know how that type check works "under the hood".

Since classes *are* modules, I assumed Ruby checks whether the argument is an actual instance of `Module`:

```
C.is_a?(Module)        #=> true
C.instance_of?(Module) #=> false
```

Sounds reasonable, doesn't it?

But when I define my own `Module` subclass and create an instance of that subclass, it works just fine:

```
class Klass < Module
end

K = Klass.new

Foo.include(K)
# no error
```

But `K` is an instance of `Klass`, just like `C` is an instance of `Class`. And `Klass` is a subclass of `Module`, just like `Class`:

```
K.is_a?(Module)        #=> true
K.instance_of?(Module) #=> false

K.class #=> Klass
C.class #=> Class

Klass.superclass #=> Module
Class.superclass #=> Module
```

So what does that type check in `include` actually do?

Is there a hidden property that allows Ruby to tell modules from classes?

Since this is implementation specific: I'm especially interested in YARV/MRI.

Comment: Maybe it directly checks if this is an instance of `Class`? `K.is_a?(Class) #=> false`, `C.is_a?(Class) #=> true`.

Comment: @MarekLipka in the C sources I see `Check_Type(module, T_MODULE)`, i.e. explicit checks for T_MODULE but no inverse like "not T_CLASS"

Answer (score 5):

As @Stefan commented, `Module#include` calls the macro `Check_Type(module, T_MODULE)`. You can find this in https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Module.html#method-i-include

Further digging the source code, you can find that in the header file **ruby.h**, there's a line

```
#define Check_Type(v,t) rb_check_type((VALUE)(v),(t))
```

so `Check_Type` is just a handy alias of `rb_check_type`, and you can find the definition of `rb_check_type` in **error.c**:

```
void
rb_check_type(VALUE x, int t)  
{ 
    int xt;                    

    if (x == Qundef) {         
  rb_bug(UNDEF_LEAKED);        
    }

    xt = TYPE(x);              
    if (xt != t || (xt == T_DATA && RTYPEDDATA_P(x))) {
  unexpected_type(x, xt, t);   
    }
}
```

The `int t` is the unique "ID" for a type, and `int xt` is the ID of the actual type of `x`. You can see `if (xt != t || ...)`, so `Check_Type` is checking the type equivalence, not the is-a relation.

### TL;DR

Ruby checks if the included module is actually a module and not a class.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm answering my own question here*

---

> Is there a hidden property that allows Ruby to tell modules from classes?

Indeed there is. Internally, all Ruby objects start with a structure called `RBasic`:

```c
struct RBasic {
    VALUE flags;
    const VALUE klass;
};
```

Within `RBasic` we have `flags` and those flags contain type information:

```c
enum ruby_value_type {
    RUBY_T_NONE = 0x00,

    RUBY_T_OBJECT = 0x01,
    RUBY_T_CLASS = 0x02,
    RUBY_T_MODULE = 0x03,
    RUBY_T_FLOAT = 0x04,
    RUBY_T_STRING = 0x05,
    // ...

    RUBY_T_MASK = 0x1f
};
```

And that's what Ruby ultimately checks for when doing the type check:

```c
#define RB_BUILTIN_TYPE(x) (int)(((struct RBasic*)(x))->flags & RUBY_T_MASK)
```

`RB_BUILTIN_TYPE` is also used by `Marshal` to dump type information:

```
module M ; end
class C ; end

Marshal.dump(M) #=> "\x04\bm\x06M"
Marshal.dump(C) #=> "\x04\bc\x06C"
Marshal.dump(4) #=> "\x04\bi\t"
#                          ^
#              m = module, c = class, i = integer
```

From within Ruby we can inspect the internal type via [Fiddle](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html):

```
require 'fiddle'

def type(obj)
  struct = Fiddle::Pointer.new(obj.object_id << 1)
  flags = struct[0]
  flags & 0x1f
end

module M ; end
class C ; end

type(M) #=> 3   (RUBY_T_MODULE = 0x03)
type(C) #=> 2   (RUBY_T_CLASS = 0x02)
```

And since Fiddle also allows to modify the underlying data, we could probably turn a class into a module by changing its flags accordingly ...

Let's give it a try: [image]

```
class C
  def hello
    'hello from class'
  end
end

class Foo
end

Foo.include(C)
#=> TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

Now the type change from `0x02` (class) to `0x03` (module):

```
require 'fiddle'

struct = Fiddle::Pointer.new(C.object_id << 1)
struct[0] = (struct[0] & ~0x1f) | 0x03

Foo.include(C)
# NoMethodError: undefined method `append_features' for C:Class
```

Still an error, but Ruby doesn't complain about the type anymore!

Apparently, `Class` undefines `Module#append_features` because the method doesn't make much sense for classes. Let's redefine it for `C`:

```
C.define_singleton_method(:append_features, Module.instance_method(:append_features))

Foo.include(C)
# no error!

Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, C, Object, BasicObject, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Foo.new.hello
#=> "hello from class"
```

And there we go: a class included in another class.

Note: I'm fiddling with Ruby's internals here. Don't use this kind of hacks in production. You've been warned.