# Extending an object with a class

Tags: ruby

TL;DR: Is there a way to add methods from a class (as opposed to a module) to a
single object?

Disclaimers: 1) I've really tried to find the answer on my own but I just
couldn't do it. 2) I once found a page that showed how to do this, but either I
failed to bookmark it or I can't find it in my (literally) 4,618 bookmarks. It
has something to do with changing the search order of methods by adding an
anonymous class.

Suppose I have a class with a bunch of methods. I want to add those methods to a
single instance of another class. Is there a way to do that?

I know how to add methods with a module. For example, consider the following
scenario:

```rb
# MyClass
class MyClass
    def method_a
        return 'this is method a'
    end
end

# ExtraMethods
module ExtraMethods
    def method_b
        return 'this is method b'
    end
end

# node
obj = MyClass.new()
puts obj.method_a # => this is method a

# add methods to object
obj.extend ExtraMethods

# call added method
puts obj.method_b # => this is method b
```

OK, that works. But suppose I want ExtraMethods to be a class, not a module? Why
would I want to do that? In my real world use case, those classes that add
methods are going to be subclassed and subsubclassed again and again.
Furthermore, those subsubsubclasses are going to be created by people who use
the gem I'm going to publish. I'd rather use the familar paradigm of class
inheritence than modules include each other.

So how could I do this? Fill in the blank:

```rb
# MyClass
class MyClass
    def method_a
        return 'this is method a'
    end
end

# ExtraMethods
class ExtraMethods
    def method_b
        return 'this is method b'
    end
end

# node
obj = MyClass.new()
puts obj.method_a # => this is method a

# add methods to object
# obj.extend ExtraMethods
YOUR_CODE_HERE

# call added method
puts obj.method_b # => this is method b
```

Comment: `familar paradigm` Perhaps to folks unfamiliar with Ruby. But in Ruby, the paradigm *is* module inclusion. If you want to mixin, you use modules. That's what they're for. If you're coming from Python, then yes, over there mixins are done with classes, but this isn't Python.

Comment: If you could insert a single instance method from another class, how should in this method a reference to instance variables be resolved?

Comment: Put your methods into a module and have the class that is going to be subclassed extend / include that module. That way, you have the methods via inheritance and also can extend / include them separately into other classes.

Answer (score 4):

It's unusual to add methods to a *specific* object instance. Usually you `include` in the `class` and they get added to all instances. You can `extend` a specific instance if necessary, and if so, it basically must be a `module`.

This is just how it's done in Ruby. It's a simple composition pattern, as opposed to inheritance:

```rb
class MyClass
  include ExtraMethods
end
```

Extending anything with a `class` is going to look weird or broken to anyone familiar with Ruby.

Comment: I suspect it is impossible to literally extend with a class. That would allow multiple inheritance, which is not permitted in Ruby.

Comment: If you `include` a `class` you get an error that it's not a module, so yeah, basically. There's probably a way to do it if you try hard enough, though.

Comment: You might be able to fake it by adding an instance of the `ExtraMethods` class and then delegating messages to it if the delegate object is non-nil. That would be pretty ugly though.

Comment: @pjs Ruby doesn't normally prevent you from doing anything, but if it's really hard to do it, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @tadman Agreed. That's why I love working in Ruby, even if I wish it were faster.

Comment: @pjs 3.x has made great strides, and the core team continues to deliver on their promises, so I can't complain too much. [3.2 will be even better!](https://shopify.engineering/ruby-yjit-is-production-ready)

Comment: @tadman I need C-like speeds to get where I want to go. Crystal is interesting, but has taken years getting ported to Windows (and is still not ready for prime-time there). Much as I'd like to, I can't just ignore Windows systems. So currently I can run my stochastic epidemiological agent-based models for up to a small city, but not for the entire population of a country.

Comment: @pjs Ruby, and when Ruby isn't enough, try Rust. It's quite different in approach but does it ever deliver in terms of speed. I hope one day that you can more seamlessly integrate the two.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advice. I've just started peeking at Rust in the last couple of weeks, wasn't sure if it could handle the dynamic dispatch my model architecture uses.

Comment: FYI: [What prevents me from including a class in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59766403/477037)

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass
  def method_a
    'this is method a'
  end
end
```

```
module ExtraMethods
  def method_b
    'this is method b'
  end
end
```

---

```
obj1 = MyClass.new
  #=> #<MyClass:0x00007fe126afc7d8>
obj2 = MyClass.new
  #=> #<MyClass:0x00007fe126ae6d98>
```

```
obj1.method_a
  #=> "this is method a"
obj2.method_a
  #=> "this is method a"
```

---

You need to `include` the module `ExtraMethods` in `obj1`'s singleton class, which can be accomplished by using [Object#extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-extend).

```
obj1.extend ExtraMethods
  #=>#<Class:#<MyClass:0x00007fe126afc7d8>>
```

This is equivalent to

```
obj1.singleton_class.include ExtraMethods
```

```
obj1.singleton_class.instance_methods.grep /method_/
  #=> [:method_b, :method_a]
```

```
obj1.methods.grep /method_/
  #=> [:method_b, :method_a]
obj2.methods.grep /method_/
  #=> [:method_a]
```

```
obj1.method_b
  #=> "this is method b"
obj2.method_b
  #=> undefined method `method_b' for #<MyClass:0x00007fe126ae6d98>
```

Comment: @pjs, that's a novel way of leaving a comment on a deleted answer! Thanks.

Comment: Btw. `select  { |m| m.match? /method_/ }` can be simplified to `grep /method_/`.

Comment: Many thanks, @cremno. I love `grep`, so why do I so often forget to use it?